# generating prime numbers on both sides of a number

Tags: c

**Problem:**

Generate a function who take a number x as argument and another number p as an argument, it then takes p number of prime no. on both left and right side and return the average of all those elements.

**Attempt:**

I wrote the following code: but I wanted to see if the time complexity could be reduced.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_prime(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;
    
    if (n == 2 || n == 3)
        return 1;
    
    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0)
        return 0;
    
    for (int i = 5; i * i <= n; i = i + 6)
    {
        if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    
    return 1;
}

double sum_of_primes(int x, int p)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int countls = 0;
    int countrs = 0;
    int count = 0;

    if (is_prime(x))
    {
        sum = x;
        count = 1;
    }

    int i = x - 1;
    int j = x + 1;
    while (countls < p)
    {
        if (is_prime(i))
        {
            sum += i;
            countls++;
            count++;
        }   
        i--;
    }

    while (countrs < p)
    {  
        if (is_prime(j))
        {
            sum += j;
            countrs++;
            count++;
        }     
        j++;
    }
    return (double)sum / count;
}

int main()
{         
   int x, p;
   scanf("%d %d", &x, &p);

   printf("%f", sum_of_primes(x, p));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What on earth is going on with your formatting?

Comment: *PLEASE* learn how to indent your code.  It's not just "style".  Correct formatting is really *ESSENTIAL* to understanding how your code is structured.  You can actually *ELIMINATE* a lot of common bugs it you just take the time and effort to align and indent your code properly...

Comment: Aside: the code fails if there are not `p` primes lower than `n`. It finds negative numbers to be prime, including `-1`, but excluding `-2` and `-3`!

Comment: @WeatherVane you have clearly identified that the code does not work as intended, why on earth would you send them to code review. We require that the code be working as intended.

Comment: @WeatherVane Consider the code reviewed, the OP of the answer is a regular on Code Review and has offered good advice for performance improvements.

Comment: @pacmaninbw thank you for your advice. That answer appeared later.

Answer (score 5):

> see if the time complexity could be reduced.

That is a worthy goal *after* getting **functionality correct**.

`is_prime(2147483647)` returns 0, yet is a prime.

This is due to overflow in `i * i <= n`.  Infinite loop when `n = INT_MAX`.  To fix:

```
// for (int i = 5; i * i <= n; i = i + 6) {
for (int i = 5; i <= n/i; i = i + 6) {
```

`is_prime(-1)`, `is_prime(-2147483647)` and various negative values return 1, yet are not primes.  To fix:

```
//if (n == 1)
if (n <= 1)
  return 0;
```

Patched code

```
int is_prime(int n) {
  //if (n == 1)
  if (n <= 1)
    return 0;

  if (n == 2 || n == 3)
    return 1;

  if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0)
    return 0;

  // for (int i = 5; i * i <= n; i = i + 6) {
  for (int i = 5; i <= n/i; i = i + 6) {
    if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0)
      return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

---

**Overflow**

With `int sum`, `sum += j;` readily overflows.  Use `long long sum`.

---

To **improve time** performance with this code that checks primality of a contiguous set of integers, research [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

This is effectively a re-write then for OP, yet it has faster execution time.

Comment: No guarantee that `long long` has greater range than `int`.

Comment: @TobySpeight True, yet a reasonable risk.